How to find CDF of the following?
I am trying to find out the CDF of the following expression that involves multiple random variables but not getting it properly.
$P = Pr (\gamma_{u_1} < \gamma_{th})$ ----(1)
where,
$\gamma_{u_1} = \frac{(|A|^2+\beta_0^2|B|^2|C|^2)\alpha_{1} }{(|A|^2+\beta_0^2|B|^2|C|^2)\alpha_2+(|D|^2+\beta_0^2|B|^4)\frac{P_{u_1}}{P_b}+\frac{1}{\bar{\gamma}}} $
such that $A, B, C,$ and $D$ are independent and identically distributed Rayleigh random variables and all other terms are constant.
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.
